My iMac takes more than 30 minutes to start after a restart
I have an iMac, 2019 with 14.3.1 MacOS. I use to keep it on Sleep, but from time to time, I need to either restart or shutdown. Whenever I do this, no matter if I chose to reopen the apps or not, it takes more than 30 minutes to become fully operational.
It takes maybe 30-60 seconds to get into the desktop, but then apps start jumping on the dock, taking ages for them to open and I cannot even move my mouse. The mail always start with the prompt that it needs to rebuild the mailbox because another device is using it.
I tried to remove as many apps as I could from the Login Items. The only apps that are there under "Open at Login" are Dropbox and Viber. However more than those 2 starts opening during startup.
I would appreciate any advice on what other steps I should do. I will update this post with any extra answer on your questions or suggestions.

Please clarify 30'. Do you mean minutes or seconds? When I first read the title, I thought you were referring to 30 feet but now I see it refers to time.

@agarza sorry for the confusion. I updated all of them to the related text metric.

First I would restart in Safe Mode, it it's faster then it IS a software problem. I also wonder if you have an issue with the HDD in this iMac. If you have an external USB drive that you can install an OS on and then boot from it, if that is faster you may have a defective HDD. Note that Apple's built in hardware test does not always diagnose HD/SSD problems accurately. So you can try it but who knows if the results are meaningful.


Try starting with all external drives disconnected. 2) As well as Apps in Login items, you will have "Allow in the Background" processes - disable all of them.


I tried Safe Mode. It was faster but still slow. Maybe instead of 30+ minutes, it was 10 minutes. I also tried the disk utilities with no errors found. I am thinking that I have never done a fresh install (format) of the OS since 2019. If that could affect it on that scale

I never thought checking it. It seems I have an SSD and not HDD.
